# ng e2e on circleci - Server terminated early with status 127

Tags: angular, angular-cli, e2e-testing, circleci, angular-e2e

I've generated a completely new and empty project with the angular 7 cli. And the first step was to setup Circle CI to test the project.

When i run this on my computer, no problem:

```
npm run lint
npm run e2e
```

Tests succeed well.

So i putted the same in my circleci config file:

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:8.12.0

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/new_project

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run e2e
```

And when CircleCi runs it, it fails:

```
[09:01:05] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.45.zip
[09:01:05] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.45
[09:01:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:01:05] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[09:01:05] E/launcher - Server terminated early with status 127
[09:01:05] E/launcher - Error: Server terminated early with status 127
at earlyTermination.catch.e (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52)
at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
  From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
  at Function.createSession (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
  at Function.createSession (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
  at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
  at Runner.createBrowser (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
  at q.then.then (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
  at _fulfilled (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
  at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
  at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
  at /home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
  at runSingle (/home/circleci/bailleur-indep-extranet/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
  [09:01:05] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
  An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

It seems that the build part of the process of testing angular goes well, no warning, no error, only classic log of building angular.

Versions:
- node:8.12.0
- @angular/cli:7.2.0 (occured too, and not solved too, with 7.1.x)
- npm:6.4.1

Any idea of how to solve it ? Thanks in advance for any help and idea !

Comment: Exit code 127 often means "command not found" (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html). Maybe the launcher attempts to exec a binary and it is not installed in the container you are using on CircleCI

Comment: Interesting ! Will try asap. Thanks for the idea !

Comment: @MathKimRobin are you able to solve it?? I am stuck at this point.

`[09:01:05] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[09:01:05] E/launcher - Server terminated early with status 127
[09:01:05] E/launcher - Error: Server terminated early with status 127`

**Can you help me if you resolved it**

Comment: Sadly not... No solution. Used a script from my boss, which was working, don't understanding what maked the difference between ours scripts. So no solution actually :s

Comment: You have chromedriver but you do not have chrome browser. You need to install eg. by commands: `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and next `apt-get update` and next `apt install --yes ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`